# Getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" error which trying to call the a function to take screenshot in a test method on Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, screenshot

I am new to the selenium automation world, Getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` error which trying to call the function to take a screenshot in a test method on Selenium. I am pretty sure I have missed initialize or return the driver somewhere. below is the code.

baseTest class where I am initializing the webdriver

```
public class baseTest {
    public Properties objProp = new Properties();
    FileInputStream readProp;
        {
        try {
            readProp = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\kiran\\IdeaProjects\\SelProject2\\src\\test\\java\\appDetails.properties");
            objProp.load(readProp);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeSuite()
    {
        System.setProperty(objProp.getProperty("browser"),objProp.getProperty("driverPath"));
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(objProp.getProperty("URL"));
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite()
    {
        if(null != driver)
        {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }
}
```

All my tests extends the baseTest function link shown below

```
public class loginFunction extends baseTest {

    guruLoginPage objLogin;
    guruHomePage objHome;
    takeScreenshot objSS = new takeScreenshot(driver);
    //readExcel readObj;


    @Test
    public void performLogin() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        objLogin = new guruLoginPage(driver);
        String loginPageTitle = objLogin.getTitle();
        Assert.assertTrue(loginPageTitle.contains("Demo Site"));

        objSS.screenshot();

        objLogin.loginAction(objProp.getProperty("appUsername"), objProp.getProperty("appPassword"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        objHome = new guruHomePage(driver);

        Assert.assertTrue(objHome.validateLogin().contains("Manger Id : mngr242657"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        objSS.screenshot();
    }
}
```

when i write this piece of code in the loginfunction, it works fine, but when i am trying to optimize and put it in a separate class and call the method I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` error

```
public class takeScreenshot{

    WebDriver driver;


    public takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver)
    {
            this.driver=driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }

    public void screenshot() throws IOException {
        String fileSuffix = DateTime.now().toString("yyyy-dd-MM-HH-mm-ss");
        TakesScreenshot ss = ((TakesScreenshot)this.driver);
        File srcFile = ss.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile,new File("C:\\Users\\kiran\\IdeaProjects\\SelProject2\\src\\test\\java\\Screenshots\\"+fileSuffix+".jpg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because when you initialize the object in your test class your driver is not initialized yet..it is still null. your driver is getting initialized as part of before class method invocation. so by that time driver is null.

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply and input, but given the above code how can i achieve the solution suggested by you, as declared i am still new to coding and did not understand where to make changes in the above code